# Rewrite Rule for Masking the URL with Query string and Page number

Tags: .htaccess, web, url-rewriting

I am trying to mask the following url with any page number using htaccess.

https://sampledomain.com/?page=2

to

https://sampledomain.com/page/2

So if we call https://sampledomain.com/page/2 url in the website, internally path should always be calling https://sampledomain.com/?page=2 url

Please suggest me the correct htaccess rule.

Comment: possibly `RewriteRule ^/page/([0-9]+)(/?)$ /?page=$1 [NC,L]`?

Comment: I tried the above rule, though it looks good but not working

Answer (score 0):

In `htaccess` in your document root, use the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)/?$ /?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I tried it, But not working. Showing 404 page

Comment: @SahithPotu It should work if you have placed it in your `/root/. htaccess` . What URL are you going to?